# Pandas replacing outlier new list to column value

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, outliers

I try to use the code from [this post](https://python.plainenglish.io/an-easy-python-code-snippet-to-replace-outliers-3aa9bc9aa80) on a subset **.iloc[:,6:]** of my dataset **df2_clean**

Original code:

```
for col in data.columns:
mean = data[col].mean()
std = data[col].std()

N = 1.5
upper = mean + N*std
lower = mean - N*std

median = data[col].median()
newcol = []
for val in data[col]:
    if val < lower or val > upper:
        newcol.append(median)
    else:
        newcol.append(val)

data[col] = newcol
```

My issue is that the list newcol is computed well but the line `df2_clean.iloc[:,6:][col] = newcol` doesn't seem to work.
It is really confusing because when I add two Prints:

```
 print(max(newcol))
 df2_clean.iloc[:,6:][col] = newcol
 print(df2_clean.iloc[:,6:][col].max(),"\n")
```

The result is

```
13.59324074073811
85.57633101852116
```

Posting my entire code (basically the same but in case) below:

```
for col in df2_clean.iloc[:,6:].columns:
    mean = df2_clean.iloc[:,6:][col].mean()
    std = df2_clean.iloc[:,6:][col].std()
    
    N = 1
    upper = mean + N*std
    lower = mean - N*std
    median = df2_clean.iloc[:,6:][col].median()
    newcol = []
    for val in df2_clean.iloc[:,6:][col]:
        if val < lower or val > upper:
            newcol.append(median)
        else:
            newcol.append(val)
    print(max(newcol))
    df2_clean.iloc[:,6:][col] = newcol
    print(df2_clean.iloc[:,6:][col].max(),"\n")
```

Comment: What is the point of saying `df2_clean.iloc[:,6:][col]`? Why not just `df2_clean[col]`?

Comment: @jprebys columns 0 to 5 have strings and I wanted to keep these columns out of the data cleaning by applying the code only to the columns with numbers (from column 6 onwards)

Comment: okay I added a df2_clean2 = df2_clean.iloc[:,6:] and re-run the code with df2_clean2  instead and it is working. will merge the string columns but still confused on why it did not work by focusing on my columns 6: only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you don't need to always use iloc as it gives you the same data as just df2_clean[col]. You just need it in the for loop to say you only want to loop through 6:.

Here's your function cleaned up a little, it should work that way:

```
for col in df2_clean.iloc[:,6:].columns:
    mean = df2_clean[col].mean()
    std = df2_clean[col].std()
    
    N = 1
    upper = mean + N*std
    lower = mean - N*std
    median = df2_clean[col].median`enter code here`()
    
    df2_clean[col] = df2_clean[col].apply(lambda val: median if val < lower or val > upper else val)
```